# In Android Method requrning multiple values best practice from memory view point

Tags: java, android

I want to return multiple values from method for this i wanted to select best way from memory & maintainability point.

Please tell me what will be the best approach only for android as i wanted to use this solution for android app.

**Method 1:**

```
public void getSomeJobDone(MyClass1 object,MyClass2 object){
}
```

If i used this way then problem is if i wanted to return one more value later then it increases code maintainability. As this method will have many usages from many points in code.

**Method 2:**

```
public HashMap<String,Object> getSomeJobDone(){
}
```

For this way if we look at the source code of HashMap it comes to know that internal it will create HashMapEntry for hash table.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-3.2.4_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/util/HashMap.java

**Method 3:**

```
public Bundle getSomeJobDone(){
}
```

Have a look at this bundle returning method it is Parcelable and dont contain much data structures in it.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Bundle.java

So should i use Solution 3 or any other approach is better.

Thanks